# Give Character Divider on Parameter Name

Tags: vb.net, parameters, naming-conventions

I Have Problem when users ask me to use `-` divider on parameter , here's what I've tried :

```
Public Function Auth(ByVal Subscriber-id As String,
                                           ByVal Country-Code As String,
                                           ByVal Resource-ID As String,
                                           ByVal Action-ID As String,
                                           ByVal IP-Address As String) As AuthOut
```

actually that script give me an error, to put comma `,` or `)` .

is it possible to naming parameter like that?

Comment: Remove hyphen, Use underscore (_).

Comment: so there's no ways to give hyphen on variable naming, okay thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Hyphen is not an allowed character in parameter name.

See restrictions on [Declared Element Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81ed9a62%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> An element name:
>
> - Must begin with an alphabetic character or an underscore (_).
> - Must contain only alphabetic characters, decimal digits, and underscores.
> - Must contain at least one alphabetic character or decimal digit it if    begins with an underscore.
> - Must not be more than 1023 characters    long.

Comment: Thank you for all the reference about variable naming :)